# Can I invoke a GNOME screen-lock from the terminal?

Tags: command-line, gnome3, screen-lock

I'm running a GNOME/Wayland desktop environment, with GDM, on a Debian-based distro. I normally [lock the screen](https://help.gnome.org/misc/release-notes/3.6/users-lock-screen.html.en) with <kbd>Super</kbd> + <kbd>L</kbd> .

Is there a command to invoke the screen-lock from the terminal?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes you can do this.

```
dbus-send --type=method_call --dest=org.gnome.ScreenSaver \
    /org/gnome/ScreenSaver org.gnome.ScreenSaver.Lock
```

From http://choffee.co.uk/thoughtsplurge/posts/2013/07/11/lock_gnome_screensaver/ via "[How can I lock my screen in Gnome 3.8 without GDM?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/86221)"

Comment: Didn't work for me on Mint 21. Even running just `gnome-screensaver` from the terminal didn't work. Odd.