# Gnome 40 issues with locking the screen

Tags: fedora, gnome, screen-lock

I recently installed Fedora 34 on my desktop and have a couple of issues with GNOME 40:

1. The screen doesn't lock. Although I have a settings Privacy > Screen Lock > Automatic Screen as enabled.
2. I tried to use the Suspend option from the Power Off menu, but it doesn't request the password.

The password is requested after I reboot the machine though.

Is it a bug or I misunderstood this option in Settings?

Comment: Seems that was because I used XDM instead of GDM. https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/86221/how-can-i-lock-my-screen-in-gnome-3-without-gdm